# Access all controls inside silverlight datagrid with template columns in c# code

Tags: silverlight

I want to access the controls inside a datagrid of silverlight, which contains template columns , inside which are checkboxes.I want some code which helps me access all checkboxes in the datagrid row by row..either on page load, or on click of a button.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the DatagridExtension ,

I have used this technique in my code, if it does not work let me know.

[Accessining rows of silverlight Datagrid](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2010/05/02/accessing-of-rows-in-silverlight-datagrid.aspx)

[Accessing controls in datagrid silverlight](http://manaspatnaik.com/blog/index.php/technology/silverlight-4/accessing-controls-in-datagrid-columnheader-silverlight/877)